# Trouble with Image Gallery

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

I am new to coding and am working on a little project. I'm trying to make an image gallery in html & css where whenever you hover over an image a larger preview of that image shows in the middle. Here's a link to a screen shot of what my gallery looks like:
[image]
As you can see it's quite simple, what I'm having trouble with is:
1. The positioning of the images so that they look the same when I open them in new browsers/computers
2. I want to know if there's a more streamlined way of coding this in css because right now what I'm doing is basically this for each image:

```
#forest {   display:inline-block;   height: 70px;   width: 70px;   margin-top: 100px;   margin-left: 70px;   margin-right: -90px; }

#previewforest {    position:absolute;   z-index:10;   height: 350px;   opacity: 0;   margin-top: -100px;   margin-right: 50px;   margin-bottom: 300px;   margin-left: 50px; }

#forest:hover{   opacity:0.4; }

#forest:hover ~ #previewforest {   opacity:1.0; }
```

Thank you I hope this was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a id you could use a class. A class can be used several times.

To use this in css you do instead of:

```
#image {}
```

you do this for a class:

```
.image { }
```

now you can use this class on every picture you have like this:

```
<div class="image">
   Picture here
</div>
```

To make your page look the same in all browsers you can reset your CSS:

http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: I'm going to try that thank you! And about CSS reset, I'm sorry but what exactly is that?

Comment: It resets all the CSS code so that it will be the same in every browser. Just take the first one and paste it on top of you css file.

For better information: http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

Comment: You might also wanna read this: http://www.cssreset.com/which-css-reset-should-i-use/